# I am not seeing dialogState in Alexa's event in AWS lambda logs, for a multiturn dialog?

Tags: alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot, alexa-skills-kit

I created an intent with slots in Alexa. This triggers an AWS lambda written in Python. I am logging the 'event'. I expect event['request']['dialogState'] to be present but it is not. Am I missing something?

Event:

```
{u'session': {u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.b2a191bb-7ee2-4fa7-aa7b-456d4bd2ee35'}, u'sessionId': u'Sessi    onId.afb747ea-01ae-4094-ba10-ac49405a99df', u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.BFHTSNCIVD2HA563BEPLRW5TSCESQEZXCIULPPB2ULOZBIJRCPM    5Z5NWOWH3HWNOZRTY4WT3FZFVGWWPKRSKC4ZNDSB2EYB45TYQ3RNY67CZPGF4GBMV6CL57C5MJVPIQPH25DQWGXGALDBCBRHMG5IA3Y26UHI7MHPIV3665ZU5OESS3UBADD7MDYQ    BWJZFB3XHJS6IM2Y5UTQ', u'accessToken': None}, u'new': False, u'attributes': {}}, u'request': {u'locale': u'en-US', u'type': u'IntentRequ    est', u'intent': {u'slots': {u'ncpu': {u'name': u'ncpu'}, u'nmem': {u'name': u'nmem'}}, u'name': u'CreateVM'}, u'requestId': u'EdwReques    tId.c9de162a-d606-43a1-9257-b7367c9da5de', u'timestamp': u'2017-10-24T09:43:17Z'}, u'version': u'1.0', u'context': {u'AudioPlayer': {u'p    layerActivity': u'IDLE'}, u'System': {u'device': {u'supportedInterfaces': {}}, u'application': {u'applicationId': u'amzn1.ask.skill.b2a1    91bb-7ee2-4fa7-aa7b-456d4bd2ee35'}, u'user': {u'userId': u'amzn1.ask.account.BFHTSNCIVD2HA563BEPLRW5TSCESQEZXCIULPPB2ULOZBIJRCPM5Z5NWOWH    3HWNOZRTY4WT3FZFVGWWPKRSKC4ZNDSB2EYB45TYQ3RNY67CZPGF4GBMV6CL57C5MJVPIQPH25DQWGXGALDBCBRHMG5IA3Y26UHI7MHPIV3665ZU5OESS3UBADD7MDYQBWJZFB3X    HJS6IM2Y5UTQ'}}}}
```

Comment: Please share the log as well of 'event'

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan updated the event log in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can not test you skills inside of the Amazon developer portal because these will not return a Dialogstate for your dialog. If you want to test your skill i suggest you go to echosim.io or get an echo dot to experiment with.

If you don't want to test with echosim.io or a real echo device and you have your skill code inside of AWS Lambda you can always test your code there with the test command.

Example:

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "SessionId.******************0ed735901",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.e96d9***********3ee1b958e6ca"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGMQGVEZFE355BBMXYBQGFN7TRN5E5CSGUU5Y3AUNEBT3DOZ7IOQ3K7G3RGIOI7BEJVLVR4CWSARSTMAF5RNA4QW************DURTSESLYMYDVIQLWA2LF6PHG3KB3UEOLZWYBBWLRKCFFMG7JFP7TNKCS2RQ4KOGPIMOT2PGQT3S2HAOBNJSAA
    }
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "dialogState": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId.5b2a45f7-e4bb-44cd-ba9f-1cfe138d577f",
    "intent": {
      "name": "SearchIntent",
      "slots": {
        "AnswerTime": {
          "name": "AnswerTime",
          "value": "Nope"
        },
        "FirstTime": {
          "name": "FirstTime",
          "value": "02:00"
        },
        "SecondTime": {
          "name": "SecondTime"
        },
        "Date": {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "2017-10-20"
        },
        "Name": {
          "name": "Name",
          "value": "Liam De Lee"
        }
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2017-10-19T13:29:17Z"
  },
  "context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.e96d95e0-8cbd-41d2-a280-3ee1b958e6ca"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGMQGVEZFE355BBMXYBQGFN7TRN5E5CSGUU5Y3AUNEBT3DOZ7IOQ3K7G3RGIOI7BEJVLVR4CWSARSTMAF5RNA4QW************DURTSESLYMYDVIQLWA2LF6PHG3KB3UEOLZWYBBWLRKCFFMG7JFP7TNKCS2RQ4KOGPIMOT2PGQT3S2HAOBNJSAA"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

> Note: Service Simulator does not currently support testing audio
>   player directives, dialog model, customer permissions and customer
>   account linking.

Amazon developer portal.

Comment: Thanks for Note! yesterday morning I was tried to use AudioPlayer and in evening tried for VideoApp, and today morning started for delegates. Due to I was testing in the simulator I was unable to do it.